# How to use Node.js `cluster` module with DT @types/node@16.x and TypeScript/commonjs?

Tags: node.js, typescript, definitelytyped

I maintain a TS app using [Node's `cluster` API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/cluster.html) that built fine with Node 14.x and Node 14.x [`cluster` types from DT](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/cluster.d.ts).

As I move this app to Node 16.x, I bumped `@types/node` from `14.x` to `16.x`, and then TS fails to compile:

- Looking at the .d.ts (both its contents and the first doc lines at the top of the file), it expects me to use a **default import**: `import cluster from 'cluster';` ...
- ... whereas my TS code currently `import * as cluster from 'cluster';` (no default import)

At that point,

- If I move to a default import, TS compiles but my app is broken
- If I stick to my `import * as ...` non-default imports, I have to add a bunch of `// @ts-expect-error` to be able to compile, and my app works.

→ What am I supposed to do? I'm asking here before filing a bug on DT, because I understand I'm possibly in a weird place because DT seems to be moving to ESM, and I'm still using TS with `commonjs` (my tsconfig has `"module": "commonjs", "moduleResolution": "node"`).

... but if I try to add an `"esModuleInterop": true` to my tsconfig, then I get a zillion other errors from various dependencies (this is a large app).

The problem is reproducible with cluster.d.ts' example at the top of the file. Here's a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=8&jsx=0&module=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAhqAxgewA4E8C0mlYAXFdAM1ABFxhUAbAV2IFMAnUI7TZ+JI0SESKZYALhABzaEUgMARgDoMAW2CVmZaADtpzOtnBdmAEzUbtu-Ye6m5ddHODLCRNsE7dYwLemPNajCysCsYKRLAAxAAyAIwADLhRAMwA7ABQIBzooH7K6FrErHzMAugA7hyQJazMKsrMWn7GoMwAHkjKmHQlxug8WgDk-GT6oGXSkBAAyqBM2hJo6Mp5WgBWsAoZYFU1oAAUSI2gcnrlAJQANMhkruxIxsbzlSUARABUyPAvoGTo7D5aXB+MhIBh0fjQTp-cIXLagACSAnuWVAdGKdweoAAAuFcG1uKgiHjWKw-iiJMx+OAZkRsipMNBuqBRLgwCy2ay0pDMNDQB9CGhArcfqTlKABvQmLcBgBuLlQ1j8fnwQTCEVLcWqzCy+U8xWgADeaEwTFAAF91WKBuhYDrubzlaBMKTUDx4GRReLnehXbBbXK0hgCvwtAxlABhAAKAFV4ABeY1MPZnBTdLQSGQBzI42B41oEolsUnsdlcih7SVBBRwSOsSFIVjYM6GtKgRYFdDdVPoCR7AAGtfrjdAABIDd7fRsGcYLYhWAwtDp032zgG25kAGJ-ADWYx3bA2rZ+ZL23QhoATcRlCFAAB5QKGIzHYNfoABqN-Ng1H9dgHN5gtiWLZlOTbNtK1uBRflYbdkzlNszTSI9s1xfFakLEkyVLcChTYBR8j2AY2mkAYrj2Mp91YK4MD8K5YGgCQtCQOhmzjAA+FswPbWBO2Ybtez7CiYLYUcDSE7c8InN0FGnC1HhMFd4PNVc0gtPRYBKb9f1AAB1Sj4FQQ5QFgSAGxKQ5sAgKN2y0dDoHyZCwHhLRKkQQyNIQCFeBcgAJcBwEjYy2AANzYI8tSUGpiimEK2D2PYagARyuGpYFYjitLA1KFDKOtXB85h7j2AAmOI4hUrjsoaYxCKqOh7D3Vg6GMAAdQYKuU1M4FcLQ9gADjK8q1243j+P7PThPYMcpL9GToBnYySEVBSVLNIA).

→ Outcomes:

1. Am I doing something wrong? If so, why is `cluster` the only Node built-in module that exhibits the issue? (I'm still very much able to `import * as process from 'process';` or `import * as os from 'os';` for example!)
2. Is "yup you need these ts-expect-error" the sad answer until my app is moved to ESM?
3. Or is there something problematic with the current DT types and I should file a bug? **EDIT** ah, I found two DT discussions that confirm the issue: [1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/54470), [2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/59229)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a bug. I found two DT discussions that confirm the issue: [1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/54470), [2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/59229).

Hadn't found them before writing this StackOverflow post because I was looking in DT Issues, but somehow they switched to Discussions.

Comment: I know this is old, but have you or anyone else found a solution to this? I am running in to the same problem in 2023